# writing numbers as sum of at least two consecutive odd positive integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

Since $24 = 3 + 5 + 7 +9$, the number $24$ can be written as the sum of at least two consecutive odd positive
integers.

(a) Can $2005$ be written as the sum of at least two
consecutive odd positive integers? If yes, give
an example of how it can be done. If no, provide
aproof why not.

(b) Can $2006$ be written as the sum of at least two
consecutive odd positive integers? If yes, give
an example of how it can be done. If no, provide
a proof why not.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Answer (score 5):

$$\text{Sum of first $n$ consecutive odd positive integers}=n^2$$
Let a number $x$ be written as the sum of consecutive odd positive integers starting from the $(m+1)^{th}$ odd positive integer to the $n^{th}$ odd positive integer.
Then,
$$x=n^2-m^2=(n+m)(n-m)$$

---

(a) $x=2005$

$$2005=5\times401=(n+m)(n-m)$$
where $n,m\in\mathbb N$.

The factorization can be done as $1\times2005$ and $5\times401$. Moreover, $n+m\gt n-m$.
Thus, in the first case,
$$n+m=2005$$
$$n-m=1$$
$$n=1003,m=1002$$
But we need at least two consecutive odd numbers, i.e., $n-m\gt1$, so this solution is not valid.

In the second case,
$$n+m=401$$
$$n-m=5$$
$$n=203,m=198$$
Thus, $2005$ can be written as the sum of odd consecutive numbers starting from the $199^{th}$ odd number to the $203^{th}$ odd number.
Hence,
$$2005=397+399+401+403+405$$

---

Similarly, solve for $x=2006$.